# I am having trouble binding DataGridComboBoxColumn to a datatable

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and I am having trouble with something that should seem like a simple job . I have a data table that I am trying to bind to a DataGridComboBoxColumn. This is my code = please advise. No combobox is showing on loading.

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ColorListData"/>

<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Color"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=   {StaticResource ColorListData}}" x:Name="myColorComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="ColorName"   SelectedValuePath="DataID" />

 code behind:

                        Dim ColorListData As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("ColorListData"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
    Dim Sql As String = "Select DataID, ColorName from Colors where StyleID = @StyleID"
    ReDim SqlP(0)
    SqlP(0) = MyData.CreateParameter("StyleID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, StyleID)
    Dim MyColorTable As DataTable = MyData.GetDataTable(Sql, "text", SqlP)
    ColorListData.Source = MyColorTable.DefaultView
```

Comment: How about removing this ridiculous property setting?: `DataContext=""`

Comment: oops that was removed in my code - i forgot to delete when i posted - any better solutions?

Comment: How about using the auto generated columns?: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ColorListData}}" />`

Comment: not sure i understand what you are saying - i am trying to bind my combobox not a grid

Comment: A `DataGrid` can generate its own columns automatically using the code that I showed you... you *are* using a `DataGrid`, aren't you?